# create label bars in titanium for the text of my labels

Tags: ios

I want to create label bars in titanium for the text of my labels. I know am supposed to add a label property but i don't know which is it.

Below is my label.

```
var label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text: 'Register',
height: 35,
width: 200,
top: 10,
color: '#336699'
});
```

what i want to achieve is something like my label text which is 'register' to be on a Colored  bar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `backgroundColor` is what you are looking for:

```
var label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Register',
    height: 35,
    width: 200,
    top: 10,
    color: '#336699',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```

You can  also change the padding with `backgroundPadding(Top/Left/Bottom/Right)`.

Comment: thanks. It worked but it only covered the text only, i need the bar to be full..like..it should stretch from the left to right side of the ios simulator. I tried setting width to be 'auto' but it still didnt work.

Comment: As I said, you can use the backgroundPadding family properties. The other solution would be to add the label to a view that has the color you want.